# How to access various Plotter methods outside my class?

Tags: python, pyvista

I'm plotting a mesh with PyVista using [`UnstructuredGrid`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.UnstructuredGrid.html#pyvista-unstructuredgrid). It's going pretty well and I managed to plot the geometry I want using `grid.plot()`.

I now want to access methods outside of `UnstructuredGrid`: for example, I want to be able to click and select on mesh elements and I see this is possible to do with the [`enable_point_picking`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.Plotter.enable_point_picking.html#enable-point-picking) method. The only problem is that this method does not belong to `UnstructuredGrid`, but to the `Plotter` class.

Does this mean I cannot use that method, or are there any workarounds?

Comment: How are you plotting your unstructured grid? With `grid.plot()`? Because that's just a convenience function that creates a `Plotter` for you. Without your adding some more details it's hard to say where your exact issue is.

Comment: This is correct, I'm using `grid.plot()`. How can I access the Plotter it's creating? Is it as simple as assigning `plotter = grid.plot()`? And thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the documentation of the `.plot()` methods you're using](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.DataSet.plot.html#plot). These methods are actually just [`pyvista.plot()`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.plot.html#pyvista.plot):

```py
>>> import pyvista as pv
>>> pv.PolyData.plot is pv.plot
True
```

This helper function is only for convenience, sparing you the trouble of setting up a `Plotter` to get a quick plot of a mesh. If you consult the documentation you'll see that there's no option to return that plotter object, so no, you can't directly use `grid.plot()` if you want additional customization not offered by `grid.plot()`.

But not to worry: it's very easy to create your own plotter:

```py
import pyvista as pv

grid = pv.Dodecahedron()
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(grid)
plotter.show()
```

[image: screenshot of dodecahedron with coloured faces and a scalar bar showing face indices as values]

Now you can customize the plotter in any way you desire, e.g. by passing `show_scalar_bar=False` to `add_mesh()` in order to disable the scalar bar. `Plotter`'s documentation [is here](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.Plotter.html), and specifically the docs of `Plotter.add_mesh()` [is here](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.Plotter.add_mesh.html). There are a lot of options, so I recommend taking your time to slowly peruse them to learn what kind of things you can easily do. And of course you have the entire `Plotter` API to use, including the `enable_point_picking` you mentioned in your question. There's a lot of things PyVista can do for you, so you should stop and learn to carefully read documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was extremely helpful in understanding how PyVista works. I have some work to do in reading the docs. Cheers!